# Bootstrap card header - same height for all

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap cards on two web-pages. On one page, the header-text is fixed so I can use min-height to match their card-header height. On the second page, those cards will be generated so I won't know the text length and the words. I want the card-header to be the same height for all in a row.

Is there any way to calculate min-height based on the biggest card-header withing a row?

I'm already using card-deck. As far as I know this is for the height of the whole card, my issue here is the card-header. The cards in general all have the same height.

[image]

Example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <div class="container">
            <div class="card-deck my-3 text-center">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-header align-items-center d-flex
                justify-content-center card-header-height">
                        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Ipsum</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img_avatar1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-header align-items-center d-flex
                justify-content-center card-header-height">
                        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img_avatar1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-header align-items-center d-flex
                justify-content-center card-header-height">
                        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img_avatar1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Update**
I had the same issue after adding a list (ul) and list-items (li) into the card-body. Took me some hours to figure out why the card-header height doesn't work anymore then. **Make sure your li text is similar in length. One of my li was too long so it was 2-lines which screws the overall look** of the card-headers again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were nearly there. You just need to use `h-100` class to make sure the height is `100%` on your `card-header` with `d-flex`

**Live Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck my-3 text-center">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Ipsum</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
          <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just found a similar question here. Looks like you're right. The only issue now is on exactly 768 to 794 px width (iPad) it doesn't work. Gonna have to check on it now before marking any solution.

Comment: @Yaerox This should work - But  you can use media queries for ipad to make sure the height stays `100%` Do you want me add the media query for ipad ?

Comment: I got some, gonna have to check on them if my issues is there ;)

Comment: By using h-100 I can delete all my media-queries which modify my cards. I still have the same issue in my code while your snippet doesn't. I couldn't find any media-query which is getting activated by changing the width of the device. Do you have any hint for me what kind of media-query you got on your mind? -- Update: Okay, so I think the issue appears as soon as I add <li> elements to the <ul> in the card-body. Gonna check on this one now.

Comment: @Yaerox So you want to have the same height if you are on the ipad ? Is this issue you are having that same height is not being applied to card headers when using ipad ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219902/discussion-between-yaerox-and-alwayshelping).

Comment: One of my li was too long so it was 2-lines which screws the overall look

Comment: @Yaerox Yeah I had a doubt on your `ul` and `li` content inside the `card-body` as mentioned in discussion  - Happy that its all sorted now.

Comment: any chance to get in contact with you for another look on this issue? Changed some of the structure and facing the same issue again. @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Yaerox i highly doubt that its possible with this kind structure
since row and col-md-4 is stopping us here :(

Comment: So I found a way for me that this is working. I'm trying to copy this into a JSFiddle to share my solution, but inside JSFiddle it doesn't work like it does in my dev-environment ... https://jsfiddle.net/1dyor4pu/ basically I added card-deck again and used d-flex on col-md-4. INot sure if this helps someone :)

Comment: This stops working as soon as I have a <div class="row"></div> inside <div class="card-header"></div>. Not having the <row> is a tough suggestion to implement. Any other suggestions?